# Cannot highlight large no. of lines using style token in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a file of 25000 lines.
I have selected 1000 lines, now if I apply style token it only highlights around 100 lines, rest of the lines are simply ignored.
Is there any other plugin to do so ?

Comment: I personally can't really understand your question! What does "apply a style token" means? Which plugin you are using?

Comment: @psxls  select some lines in Notepad++, right click -> style token -> using style (1-5), selected lines will be highlighted with color according to selected style token. But this doesn't work if no. of lines are more e.g. 1000 lines in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right. I've tested with the latest version 6.5.2 and it is obviously a bug.

I've experimented a little bit and it always stops styling at the 2048th character. All the rest is left with no style applied. I then found that this is already filed as a bug in the official bug tracker (see [#4476 Style Token Applied to Long Line Ends at Column 2048](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/bugs/4476/)).

Unfortunately I don't know of any similar plugin and a related search in the Plugin Manager and Google didn't yield any result.